# Is Islam the oldest religion?

Tags: history

I walked past a group preaching Islam on the street the other day and something they said piqued my interest.

They were repeatedly describing Islam is the 'oldest' religion. I wanted to know more, but I didn't have the courage to ask (the group seemed quite threatening if I'm honest) so I made a mental note to ask online, and... well.. here I am :)

Comment: Thanks for your interest in Islam.

Muslims believe that Islam is the oldest religion that was revealed to the first human who was Adam (AS).

And God knows best. If you have any other question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some quick background to the answer:

The most fundamental belief in Islam is that we believe there is only one God (Allah, in Arabic), and so one who submits to the word of Allah is a Muslim. We also believe that there were thousands of prophets who came over the course of history to preach the word of God, like Noah, Abraham, Jesus, Moses, David, etc. (peace be upon them all). The final messenger was Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him).

Muslims also believe that all these prophets preached the same message since the beginning of time: there is only one God worthy of worship, so worship Him. Sometimes, this message became corrupted or lost, so another messenger would come, until the very last one came. We believe all of these prophets to be Muslim, in the sense that they believed in one God, worshipped Him, and taught the exact same message. However, obviously we don't call them "Muslim," but we would call them Jewish or Christian, etc. So Islam is just a continuation of that same message, if you will. Therefore, we consider this message to be as old as the human race, since Adam (peace be upon him) was also a Muslim (one who submits to the word of God).

Answer (score 0):

Islam is the oldest religion since time memorial, as before humans. There were jinns and angels. This was before Adam and Eve. Jibreel As the first angel and all the others submit their will to God as they do whatever Allah says. From the jinns Iblis was a pious jinn who was invited by Allah to the heavens with the angels. Then Adam and Eve pbuh were also submitting their will to God. Christianity and Judaism are actually Islam as in the Bible or Torah there is no such word as Christianity or Christian. In the Quran it says the only religion permissable by God is Islam.

Answer (score -1):

If a Non Muslim is curious at any time please do not hesitate to ask its only through asking do humans learn there is nothing to be worried about just ask .
If you are curious that is good .Allah guides who he wills but you have to do your part .Islam is the oldest religion as this religion is from Allah it has not been compromised in any shape or form the quran the book authored by Allah revealed through angel gabriel to Prophet Muhammed was completed before his demise this was the last revelation and he was the seal of prophets he brought the same message ALLAH is one pray to Allah and no one else .That makes Islam the oldest relgion as Adam and Eve also prayed to Allah NOT to Jesus not to Mary or any other prophets they only prayed to ALLAH .Hope this helps and hope your curiosity leads to more questions to satisfy your own self .We are responsible to research and find the truth .Go to quran read yusha evans is great he use to be christian minister might help you .